# Get File Path from installed command line program

Tags: java, command-line, path

I have a java program which is built, packaged as a .exe executable and placed in another location (like an installed program would be).

This program is accessible on the command line because it is on the %PATH% variable.

I want the user to be able to "cd" to a directory, and launch my program taking in a relative filename such as **C:\temp>programname.exe inputfile.txt**.

So far so good, although java assumes that the relative file "inputfile.txt" is located at `<installed.exe.location\inputfile.txt>`.

How can I get java to get the current working command line directory?
e.g. **C:\temp\inputfile.txt**

Hunting around I have tried the following:

```
String inputFile = (args[0]);
System.out.println("file path: " + new File(inputFile).getAbsolutePath());
System.out.println("1: " + Paths.get("."));
System.out.println("2: " + Paths.get(""));
System.out.println("3: " + new File("").getAbsolutePath());
System.out.println("4: " + new File(".").getAbsolutePath());
System.out.println("5: " + new File(".").getCanonicalPath());
System.out.println("6: " + new File("").getCanonicalPath());
System.out.println("7: " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

which produces:

```
file path: C:\program files\testprog\bin\testprog.exe\inputfile.txt
1: .
2:
3: C:\program files\testprog\bin\testprog.exe
4: C:\program files\testprog\bin\testprog.exe\.
5: C:\program files\testprog\bin\testprog.exe
6: C:\program files\testprog\bin\testprog.exe
7: C:\program files\testprog\bin\testprog.exe
```

How can I get java to get the **C:\temp** directory?

Comment: It seems that your program changes the working directory to its own path. Can you show us the code?

Comment: `System.getProperty("user.dir")` is this what you are looking for?

Comment: There isn't anymore code really, that's a cutdown so it works in a main method.

Comment: I have tried System.getProperty("user.dir") in the above code :P

Comment: why not get the environment value using System.getenv("variable_name") and use it in your program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Launch4J, there is an option:

```
<chdir>.</chdir>
```

If you remove the . it works.

Ref:
https://sourceforge.net/p/launch4j/discussion/332684/thread/bd4993f1/